# FILTER function Google Sheets to show empty results

Tags: database, google-sheets, filtering, blank-line

I am using a "form like" google sheets to type products and search for them in a database. For that I've been using the FILTER function, and it works perfectly when all fields of the "form" are completed, but it doesn't show any result that has an ampty column in the database, so it gives incomplete information.

The formula I've used is this one

```
=FILTER(Ingresados!$B$2:$K,SEARCH(Formulario!C3,Ingresados!$C$2:C),SEARCH(Formulario!C4,Ingresados!$D$2:D),SEARCH(Formulario!C5,Ingresados!$E$2:E),SEARCH(Formulario!C8,Ingresados!$I$2:I))
```

But I want it to filter any searched item independently, no matter if a column of the other search boxes is empty, because  currently It only shows a result when all "search" conditions are filled. I tried AND/OR operators but then I get an error...

I hope anyone could help me!
Thanks in advance :D

I tried to replace FILTER conditions with IF/AND/OR operators, but didn't work
I expect to get results based on the search conditions, no matter if only one condition is fulfilled and not requiring all conditions to be TRUE in order to show results.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
=FILTER(Ingresados!$B$2:$K,IFERROR(SEARCH(Formulario!C3,Ingresados!$C$2:C))+IFERROR(SEARCH(Formulario!C4,Ingresados!$D$2:D))+IFERROR(SEARCH(Formulario!C5,Ingresados!$E$2:E))+IFERROR(SEARCH(Formulario!C8,Ingresados!$I$2:I)))
```